# how to save data in autocomplete textview

Tags: android, android-layout, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am Using a Autocomplete TextView i want that when user enter the data in the Autocomplete       textview it is automatically saved in  the adapter which is used by Autocomplete TextView and next time when the user search the same thing  , user can get the same thing in the adapter
For example i am making an app for cabs so customer have to enter the starting point suppose it is not present in  the adapter customer writes the address but next customer tried going to same location it enters the location it should be ithe drop down i have no idea how to do this
Can anybody help me out Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to save data for the user using SharedPreferences.

Loading entered data by user in past:

```
    public void loadSavedLines() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("data", 0); 
        int size = settings.getInt("size", 0);      

        if (size != 0) {                    
            String[] history = new String[size];        

        for (int i = 0; i &lt; size; i++) {     
            history[i] = settings.getString(String.valueOf(i+1), "empty");  
        }

        AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);    
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_my_dropdown, history);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoComplete.setText(saved_uri); 
    }
```

Saving after checking that not already exist:

```
public void checkThanSaveLine(String new_line, AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
    int size = settings.getInt("size", 0);
    String[] history = new String[size+1];      
    boolean repeat = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {                
        history[i] = settings.getString(String.valueOf(i+1),"empty");
        if (history[i].equals(new_line.toString())) {
            repeat = true;
        }
    }
    if (repeat == false) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();      
        editor.putString(String.valueOf(size+1), new_line.toString() );
        editor.putInt("size", size+1);
        editor.commit();
        history[size] = new_line.toString();                
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.simple_my_dropdown, history);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you are loading your data from.
What you need to do fundamentally is set a listener on your AutoCompleteTextView.

```
    autocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            //Todo update data in adapter
        }
    });
```

if you're getting data from a database you are probably using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(activity, R.layout.name_id_list_item,
                                                          cursor, new String[]{"name"},
                                                          new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
```

So your on click method would write the data back into the database.
The tricky part is that you then need to update your adapter in order for the new data to be populated.

You can do that by recreating the adapter and setting it to your `AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter()`